# TSQL "Illegal XML Character" When Converting Varbinary to XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, casting, varbinary

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in SQL Server 2016 that converts XML that was previously converted into `Varbinary` back into XML, but getting an "Illegal XML character" error when converting. I've found a workaround that seems to work, but I can't actually figure out *why* it works, which makes me uncomfortable.

The stored procedure takes data that was converted to binary in SSIS and inserted into a `varbinary(MAX)` column in a table and performs a simple

```
CAST(Column AS XML)
```

It worked fine for a long time, and I only began seeing an issue when the initial XML started containing an ® (registered trademark) symbol.

Now, when I attempt to convert the binary to XML I get this error

> Msg 9420, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
>   XML parsing: line 1, character 7, illegal xml character

*However*, if I first convert the binary to `varchar(MAX)`, then convert that to XML, it seems to work fine. I don't understand what is happening when I perform that intermediate CAST that is different than casting directly to XML. My main concern is that I don't want to add it in to account for this scenario and end up with unintended consequences.

Test code:

```
DECLARE @foo VARBINARY(MAX)
DECLARE @bar VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Nbar NVARCHAR(MAX) 

--SELECT Varbinary
SET @foo = CAST( '<Test>®</Test>' AS VARBINARY(MAX)) 
SELECT @foo AsBinary


--select as binary as varchar
SET @bar = CAST(@foo AS VARCHAR(MAX))

SELECT @bar BinaryAsVarchar                             -- Correct string output

--select binary as nvarchar
SET @nbar = CAST(@foo AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
SELECT @nbar BinaryAsNvarchar                           -- Chinese characters 

--select binary as XML
SELECT TRY_CAST(@foo AS XML) BinaryAsXML                -- ILLEGAL XML character
-- SELECT CONVERT(xml, @obfoo) BinaryAsXML                    --ILLEGAL XML Character

--select BinaryAsVarcharAsXML
SELECT TRY_CAST(@bar AS XML) BinaryAsVarcharAsXML       -- Correct Output

--select BinaryAsNVarcharAsXML
SELECT TRY_CAST(@nbar AS XML) BinaryAsNvarcharAsXML     -- Chinese Characters
```

Comment: `varchar` means ASCII, or at least, single-byte-encoded text. ® is outside the 0-127 range that isn't affected by codepages. Try with nvarchar and `CAST( N'<Test>®</Test>' as varbinary(max))`. `nvarchar` means UTF16 ie two bytes, which is why the conversion from varchar to varbinary to nvarchar failed.

Comment: Why are you doing *any* of those conversions anyway? Whatever problem you want to solve, mixing up types isn't going to help. If you have encoding errors, ensure you always use `nvarchar` fields, parameters *and* string literals.

Comment: BTW this means that the conversions that worked are actually wrong - they depend on using the same encoding both when converting to varbinary and back to text

Comment: Finally, why did the SSIS package store *text* into a *varbinary* column? That just *begs* for conversion issues. I suspect the initial author used `varchar`, run into conversion issues and instead of using the correct column collations or switching to `nvarchar`, just covered up the problem by using `varbinary`. That didn't fix anything, just moved the encoding problems to the reader. That worked as long as there were no non-Latin characters (which wouldn't have caused problems with varchar either). When the first non-Latin character was added, *boom*, the reader failed

Comment: Inlined transformations from question: `CAST(CAST( '<Test>®</Test>' AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))` Uh, don't do that. The fundamental rule of character encodings is to read with the encoding that was used for writing.

Comment: @TomBlodget Although your statement is perfectly correct, I assume that the OP has to deal with rubbish produced by someone else. SQL-Server is not very mighty in dealing with encodings. Might be, that *read with the encoding that was used for writing* is impossible in this place...

Comment: @Shnugo Once it figured out how the data was mangled perhaps it can be reversed, using SQL CLR if necessary.

Comment: @TomBlodget That's what I mean... I many if my projects it would not be allowed to use CLR functions... Sometimes we have to go deal with rubbish. I think a multi-cast from varbin to varchar, then to nvarchar and finally to xml might solve this, as shown in my answer...

Comment: I think the original author used varbinary as a way to circumnavigate the string character limit in SSIS. After reading through everyone's comments, I tried a quick rework of the package + SQL table to use unicode string + nvarchar and ran into this error `Description: "Unicode data is odd byte size for column 11. Should be even byte size.".`

From what I've read, you can solve this issue by explicitly defining an even string length, but then SSIS limits you to 4000 characters.

Comment: I think my solution is going to be to load the original XML directly into a SQL XML column using OPENROWSET and SQL bulk import in a script task

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to know:

- SQL-Server is rather limited with character encodings. There is `VARCHAR`, which is *1-byte-encoded extended ASCII* and `NVARCHAR`, which is `UCS-2` (almost the same as `utf-16`).
- `VARCHAR` uses *plain latin* for the first set of characters and a codepage-mapping provided by the collation in use for the second set.
- `VARCHAR` **is not utf-8**. `utf-8` works with `VARCHAR`, as long as all characters are 1-byte-enocded. But `utf-8` knows a lot of 2-byte-enocded (up to 4-byte-enocded) characters, which would break the internal storage of a `VARCHAR` string.
- `NVARCHAR` will work with almost any 2-byte encoded character natively (that means with almost any existing character). But it is not exactly `utf-16` (there are 3-byte encoded characters, which would break SQL-Servers internal storage).
- XML is not stored as the XML-string you see, but as an hierarchically organised physical table, based on `NVARCHAR` values.
- The natively stored XML is really fast, while any text-based storage will need a very expensive parse-operation in advance (over and over...).
- Storing XML as string is bad, storing XML as `VARCHAR` string is even worse.
- Storing a `VARCHAR`-string-XML as `VARBINARY` is a cummulation of things you should not do.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @text1Byte VARCHAR(100)='<test>blah</test>';
DECLARE @text2Byte NVARCHAR(100)=N'<test>blah</test>';

SELECT CAST(@text1Byte AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS text1Byte_Binary
      ,CAST(@text2Byte AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS text2Byte_Binary
      ,CAST(@text1Byte AS XML) AS text1Byte_XML
      ,CAST(@text2Byte AS XML) AS text2Byte_XML
      ,CAST(CAST(@text1Byte AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) AS text1Byte_XML_via_Binary
      ,CAST(CAST(@text2Byte AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) AS text2Byte_XML_via_Binary
```

The only difference you'll see are the many zeros in `0x3C0074006500730074003E0062006C00610068003C002F0074006500730074003E00`. This is due to the *2-byte-encoding* of `nvarchar`, each second byte is not needed in this sample. But if you'd need far-east-characters the picture would be completely different.

The reason why it works: SQL-Server is very smart. The cast from the variable to XML is rather easy, as the engine knows, that the underlying variable is `varchar` or `nvarchar`. But the last two casts are different. The engine has to examine the binary, whether it is a valid `nvarchar` and will give it a second try with `varchar` if it fails.

Now try to add your *registered trademark* to the given example. Add it first to the second variable `DECLARE @text2Byte NVARCHAR(100)=N'<test>blah®</test>';` and try to run this. Then add it to the first variable and try it again.

What you can try:

Cast your binary to `varchar(max)`, then to `nvarchar(max)` and finally to `xml`.

```
,CAST(CAST(CAST(CAST(@text1Byte AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML) AS text1Byte_XML_via_Binary
```

This will work, but it won't be fast...